# CSS pre-processor language that compiles to JavaScript instead of CSS viable?

Tags: javascript, css

I always use a CSS pre-processor for web-related projects. A CSS pre-processor pretty much lets you do everything that CSS lets you do, but enables DRY coding principles and cleaner syntax. I'm wondering though - why not drop the style sheets completely? Why not make a styling-language that compiles to JavaScript instead? JavaScript apparently has full control over CSS styles anyway so it should be possible. Such a language would also be much more powerful than vanilla CSS since it would enable logic, such as selectors based on element sizes and positions, browser window size etc. A contrived example of possibilities:

```
div#test {
    if windowWidth > 800px {
        width: (windowWidth / 3 + 10)px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    else {
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
    }
}
```

Or a div that is positioned absolutely, but should follow the window when it scrolls too far down:

```
div#side_panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 25px;

    if windowScrollY > 90px {
        position: fixed;
        top: 10px;
    }
}
```

I have Googled this topic to the best of my ability without any success. **Are there any styling languages that allows for dynamic styles such as those in my example, and compiles down to JavaScript?** If not, why not? Is this not viable performance-wise? Or are there perhaps browser support issues?

---

I know some browsers, including Chrome, exposes an object called `document.styleSheets` that gives JavaScript full control over the document's styles, which would be perfect for this kind of project.

Comment: Sounds like [Dynamic CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Cascading_Style_Sheets), or possibly [Less](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/). Take a look at the "CSS" of [the Nib plugin](https://github.com/visionmedia/nib/blob/master/lib/nib/gradients.styl) for Stylus, it's almost like a new language but it compiles to very neat CSS. Although not sure it will do what you need

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Less compiles to vanilla CSS. Dynamic CSS is just a term for style sheets that are generated by the server side.

Comment: @elclanrs: Unfortunately, Stylus compiles to CSS. The title of my question says "...compiles to JavaScript instead of CSS...".

Comment: I look forward to seeing the library you write in a few months. :)

Comment: Less seems very interesting! I'll take a look!

Comment: Take a look on Less. If you really wanna use it as JavaScript, you can use the less file and less.js, it's like a language that js will parse and process!

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago I thought about it too.

In my conclusions, the first point is that CSS is meant for *web designers* and not for web developers. Designers are very creative on making the same artistic work again and again and again, but are also very dumb in programming logic and understand programming languages. Those simle if-else's would be enough to drive them crazy.

The other, is performance. CSS is meant to style a whole page layout. Even with AJAX, JavaScript is meant to do little changes and handle small user interactions. Simplicity is also at hand, imagine if we'd use only JavaScript to build a whole layout out of a HTML document.

There's also the stability concern. CSS parsing and processing is handled by browser's engine, which is very well tested, much more than our own JS codes. If we use Unobstructive JavaScript, our WebSite will be fully working when CSS is applied and images are loaded, therefore if JS bugs it will still work. Imagine if JavaScript code that lays out a page crashes. And for that, all we need is an infinite loop, which for sure would be available.

Lastly, we must separate content-HTML, look-CSS and feel/behavior-JavaScript. Therefore, just serve all content in the HTML document, even if it's gonna stay hidden. Style everything in a working manner with CSS and provide the best static page possible. Then use JS just to do changes on the layout and use if-else's when needed to change it.

Comment: _but are also very dumb in programming logic and understand programming languages. Those simle if-else's would be enough to drive them crazy_ Yes, that explains the success of things like Sass.